# Simple Analysis Question On Upper/Lower Bound of Real Number

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $a$ be real number with $a \geq \varepsilon$ for some $ \varepsilon >0$. Am I allowed to conclude that $a>0$?

My thinking is "yes" and my reasoning is as follows: Suppose not, then $ a \leq 0$. Now picking $\varepsilon >0$ such that $a\geq \varepsilon$, I obtain
$$
0< a \leq 0
$$
which is absurd. Is my logic above correct or I simply made some mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: There is no real number $a$ such that $a\ge \varepsilon$ for *all* $\varepsilon > 0$.  Such an object must be infinite.

Comment: How did this question come up? As $x \le y$ and $y< z$ *ALWAYS* means $x < y$ there really isn't much to think about.  You might want to review how the axioms of order (particularly tricchotomy and transitivity) prove this, but in general it isn't really meant to be a brain scratcher.

Comment: On the other hand proving that if $0 \le a < \epsilon$ for *all* $\epsilon > 0$, then we can prove $a = 0$, is not so trivial and obvious but none the less true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to have $a\geq \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Indeed, take $\varepsilon:=\max\{1,a+1\}$. Then $\varepsilon>0$ and $\varepsilon\geq a+1>a$.

I think you mean to ask if we have $a\geq \varepsilon$ **for some** $\varepsilon>0$, then can we conclude $a>0$? The answer to this question is "yes" by the transitivity of "$<$":
$$
0 < \varepsilon \leq a.
$$

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, Please let me fix my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction. Assume $a\leq0$ then by Trichotomy Property of R, exactly one is true $a=0$ or $-a>0$.

(i) $a=0$ then $a-\varepsilon=-\varepsilon<0$ which contradicts to the given information that $a-\varepsilon\geq0$

(ii) $-a>0$ then by Order Property of R $-a+\varepsilon>0$ and then $\varepsilon>a$ which again contradicts to the given information.

Thus by contradiction $a>0$

Answer (score 1):

"Let a be real number with a≥ε for some ε>0. Am I allowed to conclude that a>0?"

Um... Transitivity.

You have $a \ge \epsilon > 0$.  So $a > 0$.

If you *really* need a proof, below are the neausiating details:

$a \ge \epsilon$ means either $a > \epsilon$ or $a = \epsilon$.

Case 1:  $a > \epsilon$ and $\epsilon > 0$ so $a > 0$.

Case 2: $a = \epsilon$ and $\epsilon > 0$.  So substitute $\epsilon$ for $a$.  $a > 0$.